# Retrieving data from existing Tables in MySQL using django app

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have an existing Table in Mysql database. I want to retrieve the values from the table and show them in grid using a Template.

Comment: What did you try so far and what exact difficulties do you encounter?

Comment: you can check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/

Answer (score 5):

In your settings assigning the values in DATABASES variable.

```
    DATABASES = {
    # after your 'default' connection:
    'legacy_db': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'old_db',
    'USER': '',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': '',
    'PORT': '',
```

- Auto generate the django models using [inspectdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb)

  ```
  $ python manage.py inspectdb > /your_app/models.py
  ```

  It will generate models your existing Table.

note: If you use the MyISAM storage engine please be aware of foreign-key constraints. django detects fk fields on InnoDB engine only.

- Retrieve your data from existing MySQL tables using [multiple-databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/multi-db/#multiple-databases)

get your objects [selecting-a-database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database-for-a-queryset)

```
>>> # This will run on the 'legacy_db' database.
>>> Foo.objects.using('legacy_db').all()
```